# How to convince people to write code instead of gibberish long paragraphs?

Tags: discussion, answers, code

As hackers our common language are the programming languages. Since most of us spend more time writing code than blogs I think it is only normal for us to express ourselves better with code.

But a lot of people in SO are still writing long paragraphs trying to describe the answer, while it could have been much shorter, easier and clearer if they just wrote the code with some comments.

I am aware that SO isn't a site to get people do the coding for you, but it is really more convenient to have some concrete code or diagrams or whatever, anything is better than a long wall of text like this. (At least this is somewhat structured)

So how can we convince people to write less WoT and more code? Should this be handled within the question? Is there a way to influence the culture somehow? Should we warn people with comments?

tl;dr:

[image]

Comment: Downvote and flag to close as being `unclear`, `why isn't this code working`, etc. Getting their questions downvoted or closed will convice any user that, they've done something wrong.

Comment: SO users are learning that a snippet is important.  This does go wrong often, they'll just post complete nonsense and get answers about their nonsense instead of their problem.  This glass is not half full.

Comment: I very rarely see _answers_ with too much text and not enough code. Answers with just a code block and no proper explanation of what's going on seem more common. Can you show examples of answers that fit your "too much text" category?

Comment: @Mat: I feel like the majority of my answers (especially in [css](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a106224%20[css])) falls under the OP's description. They tend not to have as many votes as my all-time top scorers, probably for the same reason given here.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I think the OP is talking about answers, not questions.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah THX for pointing out this, I didn't really spot this subtlety from the question.

Comment: If it's ok to play devil's advocate: You're averaging about 0.4 upvotes/answer, with the more recent numbers being lower (about 0.2 upvotes/answer since beginning of November). Are you completely confident that your preferred style of answering is the most effective one?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Where did you look at that data? Since november I am posting new answers to 3 year old questions with 100 voted answers. I am trying to answer every possible objective-c question with a swift syntax. I am not racing to post the first answer to easy questions. I think am being helpful by updating deprecated posts so this community evolves with new technology.

Comment: @Esq I looked at your profile. I'm not at all saying that you're not making positive contributions. It just seems like a stretch to request that everybody should be answering the same way you do.

Comment: Personally I absolutely *hate* simple "here's some code" answers. I'm not interested in copying some code and putting it inside my project; I'm interested in easily seeing the underlying problem and having some background explanation. If I have to skim through code to get a sense of what the problem was then that is a very poor answer in my eyes.

Comment: *Completely* disagree. The code is the least important part of the answer. The "wall of text" explaining what the actual problem was and why an answer fixes it, and why it is the *correct* solution, is the important part. I almost always find code-only answers worth downvoting.

Answer (score 7):

This issue has two very distinct sides to it. On one hand, I can understand what you're talking about. A snippet of code with short explanation can be preferable to long paragraphs of text with no code. As I often comment on questions, "Imagine you're writing an e-mail to a coworker. It shouldn't be an essay."

However, I completely disagree that just code with some comments is the best way to answer the questions.

For the cases that someone is asking about a homework assignment, giving pure code both encourages the behavior and doesn't help the person asking the question in the long run (they learn nothing but copy+paste).

For the cases where someone is asking about how/why a language functions, code is much less useful than a thorough, well-written explanation (see many of the top-voted questions on StackOverflow).

For many other cases, code is not appropriate to answer the question ([Android R is not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649208/what-is-the-meaning-of-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-error-in-android-studio)).

In some cases, code is better than an explanation, but the whole point is to write answers that will be helpful to future readers which, I think, entails a solid explanation to help them understand what is going on.

Maybe the best course of action is something in between - code *and* a well-written explanation. However switching to the approach of throwing code fragments at the OP isn't something I would condone.

Comment: Few things bug me more than a question asking for *explanation* and answered with "Try this: `(500 lines of code)`. [Recent (random!) example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27611941/2564301), see also the other answers that *do* add explanations.

Comment: lol, you guys are right there is an appropriate place for type of answer

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of Stack Overflow (and the Stack Exchange network in general) is not only to provide answers to one person, but also to provide answers to people who end up here from Google searches expecting (and usually getting) high quality answers. While a code snippet can sometimes be just what you need, it usually isn't very helpful without a bit of explanation, even if that's just to explain why it's needed.

It can sometimes be frustrating to have to read through these explanations when you're looking for a quick answer, but understand that someone put in the effort to help you figure out your problem *for free*, which is a big deal. If there's an explanation, it's there for a reason, and it's not really fair to complain.

If there's no code at all, that's usually for good reason as well. You might want to rephrase your question to make it sound less like a homework question (typically, giving away code to people isn't recommended if it sounds like homework because it's cheating) or simply wait for other answers.